# Improve HTML5 Canvas frame by frame JPG animation to fully cache before animating

Tags: ios, caching, animation, html5-canvas, autoplay

I'm trying to build on top of this great script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779674/frame-by-frame-animation-in-html5-with-canvas) which was answered by Phrogz.

The problem is that the animation won't play until all the images have cached in the browser. Therefore, on first load it won't play. Only on a reload.

The point of me trying to do this is I'm trying to provide an alternate solution to getting an animation to autoplay since that feature doesn't work in iOS browsers.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
         function draw() { 
            var imgNumber = 1;
            var lastImgNumber = 121;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image;
            img.onload = function(){
            ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height );
            ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
            };
            var timer = setInterval( function(){
              if (imgNumber>lastImgNumber){
                clearInterval( timer );
              }
             else{
                img.src = "jpg_80/t5_"+( imgNumber++ )+".jpg";
              }
            }, 1000/24 ); //Draw at 24 frames per second
          }
```

I've tried adding this before the closing body tag:

```
                 window.onload = draw;
```

However, I believe that the code would have to be changed within the draw() function. Somewhere in the setInterval function?

Comment: Do you want to load all 121 images first, and then start the animation?

Comment: When you have an animation of 121 jpeg frames, you should maybe use a `<video>` instead.

Comment: @ Philipp Yes, however, the point is for this animation to autoplay in iOS. Otherwise, I would just use  <video autoplay="autoplay">

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, preload images and then start animation. If you have iPhone or iPad test on this link to see my problem. Doesn't load on first request: http://html5canvas.syntheticmedia.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a modified version of your `draw` function which preloads all images before putting them on a canvas.

It assumes you have a canvas with id 'anim' (as there is no reference of the canvas in the source you provided)

```
<canvas id='anim' width='660' height='500'></canvas>
```

JavaScript: (tested on an iPad)

```
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('anim').getContext("2d");
    var start = 1, stop = 121,cur=start,imgArr=[];

    var loadLoop = function() {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.onload = function() {
            imgArr.push(this);
            cur++;

            if(cur > stop) {
                // all images preloaded
                animate();
            }
            else {
                loadLoop();
            }
        }

        img.src = "jpg_80/t5_"+(cur)+".jpg";
    }

    loadLoop();

    function animate() {
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imgArr.shift(), 0, 0 );
            if(imgArr.length == 0) {
                // no more frames
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        },1000/24);
    }
}
```

Comment: You solved it! I've tried to solve this for a long time. Tested and works on iPad in Safari and Chrome.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create 121 `<img>` elements and add an `.onload` function to each of them. In that handler you increment a number, and when it reaches 121, you start the animation.

But what you are trying to do sounds like you want to create a video clip. When that's your intention, the `<video>` tag might be a better solution. A 121 frame video clip encoded with a modern codec will be much smaller than 121 separate JPEGs, because video compression algorithms use redundancies between frames to improve compression.

Comment: I compressed the 121 images to where they are just slightly bigger than the MP4. The MP4 is 2.2 mb and the 121 images are 2.8 mb. So, size isn't an issue. I understand that this will make 121 HTTP requests, however I will cache them that way it will only need to be done once. Once it is cached the animation works just fine. Even on iPhone 4s.

Comment: I've tried merging the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394136/how-to-optimize-animation-on-canvas-html-5I think you are saying will solve this problem, but haven't been successful. Do you have a code example?

Comment: If I had the answer, I wouldn't post a question sir. I'm asking for a code example because you answered the question, however, it isn't specific enough answer for me to accept.