# Make jpeg canvas animation "responsive"

Tags: animation, jpeg, media

[Improve HTML5 Canvas frame by frame JPG animation to fully cache before animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904252/improve-html5-canvas-frame-by-frame-jpg-animation-to-fully-cache-before-animatin#new-answer)

The above code snippet is great. I'd like to be able to apply new widths with css/media queries to the canvas that holds the jpgs. Is there a way to add that to the above code?

when I tried it my jpg's became wildly oversized.

It appears in the above code that the height and width declared in js for the image and the height and width on the canvas tag need to match or things get wonky.

I want to dynamically call the image width with CSS and media queries.
thanks

```
<style type="text/css">
/*CSS for full screen animation.You may want to remove this*/
html,body { 
height:100%; 
width:100%; 
padding:0; 
margin:0; 
}
/*ID for Canvas JPG Animation - Sets size, background image and loader*/
#anim { 
background-image:url('images/icon_loading_75x75.gif'),url('images/t5.png');
/*Center=Loading GIF, Left Top= Placeholder Image*/
background-position: center, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:500px; 
width:660px;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
function draw() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('anim').getContext("2d");
var start = 1, stop = 121,cur=start,imgArr=[];

//Pre-loads Images
var loadLoop = function() {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function() {
imgArr.push(this);
cur++;

if(cur > stop) {
// all images preloaded
animate();
}
else {
loadLoop();
}
}

//img.src = "jpg_80/t5_"+(cur)+".jpg";
img.src = "http://html5canvas.syntheticmedia.net/jpg_80/t5_"+(cur)+".jpg";
//jpg_80/t5_88.jpg
}

loadLoop();

//Canvas JPG Animation
function animate() {
var timer = setInterval(function() {
ctx.drawImage(imgArr.shift(), 0, 0 );
if(imgArr.length == 0) {
// no more frames
clearInterval(timer);
}
//Framerate @ 24 Frames per Second
},1000/24);
}
}
</script>
<script src="modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<body>
 <!-- HTML5 Canvas Animation-->
<canvas id="anim" width="660" height="500"></canvas>

<script>
//call after page loaded
window.onload = draw; 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post the code modifications you tried?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wegxbqdiumn8vk/animate.html if you edit the canvas tag-remove the height and width the images don't hold their height and width-the images themselves seem to take on the width (maybe) of the browser window but are cropped by an area that matches the size listed in the css

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code to it. Linking to off site code like this is generally frowned upon.

Comment: sorry.added some code