# JQuery Cross-Browser Performance: .animate() on .hover() on more than 100 DOM elements

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization, animation, cross-browser

This is my quandary.

### Let me just set the scene:

I have a grid of absolutely positioned elements, whose height, width and position(top and left) are a percentage of their container's. Essentially it is a grid of boxes that will dynamically resize to always fit the window's width while at the same time holding a steady aspect ratio. Each of these boxes should be a clickable link and must contain text that will resize appropriately as they resize.
The HTML looks somewhat like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- The container's width is 95% of the window -->
    <img alt="" src="images/aspect-holder.png">
    <!-- This image makes sure the container retains the correct aspect ratio* -->
    <a href="link1" class="element col1 row1">
        <span>Some</span>
        <span>Text</span>
              ...
    </a>
    <a href="link2" class="element col1 row2">
        <span>Other</span>
        <span>Text</span>
              ...
    </a>
    <a href="link3" class="element col1 row3">
        <!-- as above -->
    </a>
              ...
              ...
    <a href="link100something" class="element col18 row9">
        <!-- as above -->
    </a>
</div>
```

*The technique of [using an image to preserve aspect ratio is explained here](http://lab.veille.jp/aspectratio/)

The CSS for the grid is pretty straightforward and the only thing noteworthy is that I am setting the font-size of the spans in the anchor tag as percentages so that I can use JQuery to manipulate them all easily by either manipulating the font size of their parent (the anchors) or their parent's parent (the #container).

### Now as for the Problem:

What I wanted, apart from the dynamic nature of the grid, was that whenever the user hovers over one the boxes it should then "zoom in". Essentially on mouseenter the box would increase in height and width and decrease its top and left margin to 'pop' out of the page.
The following is the JQuery that I wrote to put it all together:(apologies for any glaring mistakes, I am here to learn)

```
container = $('#container');
anchor = container.find('a');
//The Globals have more unique names but I wrote them like this here
//to make it easier to read

//This part handles the font-size resize on Load and on Resize
function fontfix() {
    container.css('font-size', anchor.width() + 'px');
}

$(function() {
    fontfix();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    fontfix();
});

//This is the code that handles the 'smooth' hover* animation
anchor.hover(function() {
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').css('z-index', 2).animate({
        marginTop: '-1.9%',
        marginLeft: '-1.5%',
        height: '15%',
        width: '8%',
        fontSize: '157%'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', 1).animate({
        marginTop: '0%',
        marginLeft: '0%',
        height: '9.5393%',
        width: '5.2604%',
        fontSize: '100%'
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('style', '');
    });
});
```

*The .filter(':not(:animated)') is based off of an article on [full Jquery animations](http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/) by Chris Coyier of CSS-Tricks.

And this works! ...Well, on WebKit and Opera, or on other browsers for fewer than about 30 or 40 elements. With 100+ elements on Firefox 10 its stuttery and somewhat laggy and on IE8 its practically a slideshow. This has frustrated me no end, as I hoped to make it as cross-browser as possible and so I really hope you girls and guys can help.

### So to Sum Up

1. Have I fudged the Globals? Should I use something different?
2. Is there a way to make the animation work smoothly on all browsers?
3. Are there any other tweaks to this code you would make? Or anything else to note?

Thank you for reading this far and sorry for the long post! Any help with this is appreciated.

### Demo on JsFiddle

The link to the fiddle is `http://jsfiddle.net/kkubD/`
As is, it works like a dream on Chrome, on FF you should see stuttering and on IE even more stuttering.

As an aside, I realize I could and possibly should use an unordered list and thus wrap all my anchors in `<li>`s, but I could not find a sufficiently compelling reason to do so as the grid in its current format looks satisfactory (better even) even without CSS enabled. I guess I would find improved crawlability or performance a good enough reason, but don't know that it would add anything. Am I wrong at all in this?

Comment: Are your elements floated? There is a known issue with floated elements and animations in Firefox: http://alexw.me/2010/12/firefox-problems-with-javascript-animation/

Comment: No, they are absolutely positioned. The div#container has relative positioning and the anchors within have absolute positioning.

Comment: Be less ambitious - animate less properties - eg. take marginTop and marginLeft out of the animation and set them in a competion callback instead. For sure it's not exactly what you want but maybe that's a compromise you have to accept.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I just tried what you suggested (simply removed the margin animations) but its still not smooth on FF or IE.

Comment: @Christian Varga, I also tried what was suggested in the article (to remove float from all divs using: *{float:none} ) and that also had little effect. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Might help to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) with your exact html/css/js combo. Then we might be able to modify it to increase performance :)

Comment: try using [css3 transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/)

Comment: @ChristianVarga I added the Fiddle.

Comment: Actually it already looks pretty smooth for me in FF (13" 2011 Macbook Pro). Removing the `fontSize` property from the animation makes it even smoother. You could try the `text-rendering` property, has no effect on OSX though. Or figure out a way to do it without animating the font size :p

Comment: @ChristianVarga Sadly its not smooth for me, and as I said IE is even worse.. I would have liked this to be as cross-browser as possible, including earlier releases of some (not as far back IE6 o'course, but for 8 at least yes), thus CSS transitions would only be used with progressive enhancement, but that still leaves us with IE8 being left behind.

Comment: @rkw is there a way to achieve the effect I demo in the fiddle using transitions? I tried but cannot get the transition `mouseleave` animation to wait until the transition `mouseenter` animation is complete before it kicks in (whereas with jquery this is handled by the ".filter(':not(:animated)')"). Thus when using CSS transitions the visual effect is somewhat inelegant. [Here's the fiddle that shows what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/kkubD/4/)

Comment: try to make your selector `$(this).filter(':not(:animated)')` less verbose. I also guess it would run smoother if you could use `px` instead of `%` since they have to be recalculated into `px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max,

I have had a good old play with this and come up with something better, at least in 
Opera which was initially slugging in the way you describe for FF.

The result is a 2-step custom animation with instantaneous first-step then a `setTimeout()` for delay before the second step. Each step uses `.css(...)` to invoke one of three hard-coded maps.

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handling is delegated to the container and, though this doesn't appear to be particularly important to performance (on my hardware), it should consume less memory.

Overall, I find the resultant performance varies depending on the vagaries of how big a timeslice the OS (Win 7 here) decides to give my Opera tab. At its worst, the visual effect is still slightly sluggish and at its best very smooth. This varies from minute-to-minute and refresh-to-refresh.

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var iam_container = $('#container');
    var iam_anchor = iam_container.find('a').data('t', null);

     $(window).resize(function() {
        iam_container.css('font-size', iam_anchor.width() + 'px');
    }).resize();

    var css_0 = {
        marginTop: 0,
        marginLeft: 0,
        height: '9.5393%',
        width: '5.2604%',
        fontSize: '100%',
        zIndex: 0
    };
    var css_1 = {
        marginTop: '-0.95%',
        marginLeft: '-0.75%',
        height: '12.27%',
        width: '6.63%',
        fontSize: '125%',
        zIndex: 1
    };
    var css_2 = {
        marginTop: '-1.9%',
        marginLeft: '-1.5%',
        height: '15%',
        width: '8%',
        fontSize: '157%',
        zIndex: 2
    };

    function anim($elem, map, delay) {
        clearTimeout($elem.data('t') || null);
         $elem.css(css_1).data('t', setTimeout(function(){$elem.css(map);}, delay));
    }

    iam_container.on('mouseenter', 'a', function() {
        anim($(this), css_2, 50);
    }).on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
        anim($(this), css_0, 50);
    });
});
```

50ms timeout delay is experimental and may be better at 100ms or 150ms, otherwise the intermediate animation step may not be perceived on faster hardware.

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ8Pj/9/):

Comment: Hey @Beetroot-Beetroot, I tried to upvote yr answer but annoyingly I need 15+ rep to have that privilege.. In any case thanks, your code works better for me in IE and FF. In mine, I've already changed my js to all be included in one `$(function() {` like yours and have also moved the handler to the container using `.on('mouseenter' ..etc` now I'll see whether I can get this css map method to run a bit more fluidly. I might end up using different fx for Webkit and different for the rest.. we'll see.

Comment: As for the timeout delay I once found another SO question addressing the issue and it is certainly a good read. [If you want to check it out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136644/how-do-i-make-a-javascript-animation-play-at-the-same-speed-on-all-browsers-on-a)

Comment: Max, a way to improve fluidity is to compromise on the intermediate map, css_1. By simplifying; the effect at this short-lived transitional state, there would be less work for the processor when the user scans over the elements. My technique allows for this whereas a standard jQuery animation does not.